# Change css properties of parent element when hover on child element

Tags: html, css, parent-child

I am trying to change properties of parent element when hover on child element. Here is my HTML

```
<div class="social-icons">          
    <div class = "innerSocialDiv">
        <a href="#" target="_blank" class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg" title="facebook"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to change a CSS property of `innerSocialDiv` when hovering on `fa-facebook`.

Here is what I did in my CSS:

```
.fa-facebook:hover  + .innerSocialDiv{
    background-color: black;
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 2):

CSS always work `left to right` and `top to bottom` way. When you hover a child element then it's parent automatically called hover state. 
Instead of this you can directly use following CSS

```
.innerSocialDiv:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `+ .innerSocialDiv`, you can just use:

```
.fa-facebook:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: @Carl Jan : I know how how to achieve this using JQuery, but I need to done this using CSS only

Answer (score 0):

Try this JQuery

```
$(".fa.fa-facebook").hover(function(){
    $(".innerSocialDiv").css("background-color", "black");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### This is working code

```
.fa-facebook:hover .innerSocialDiv{
background-color: black;
```

}

Comment: can you send me fiddle